# Scala : Add an implicit method to transform case class to another case class in alias object?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, implicit-conversion, implicit

I am new to Scala and I have a case class like this:

```
case class Student(
 name: String,
 age: Option[Int] = None,
 id: String
)
```

and another case class like this:

```
case class Member(
 id: String,
 `type`: String,
 name: String
)
```

I want to create a helper implicit in such a way that:

```
case class Member(
 id: String,
 `type`: String,
 name: String
)

object Member {
  implicit def toStudent(member:Member):Student = Student(member.name,None,member.id)
}
```

and then call the method like this:

```
val newMember = Member("abc","Student","John")
val student = newMember.toStudent
```

or something fancy like that. Would this be possible in Scala as I see a lot of fancy syntax similar to this at a lot of places?

Comment: Why an extension rather than defining the method directly on the class?

Comment: We wanted to have it on case class

Comment: _"We wanted to have it on case class"_ so what? Just define it in the case class body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala 3 you can use [extensions methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html):

```scala
// ...

extension (member: Member)
  def toStudent: Student = Student(member.name, None, member.id)

val newMember = Member("abc", "Student", "John")
val student = newMember.toStudent
```

For Scala 2 you can define explicit conversion:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions
object Member {
  implicit def toStudent(member: Member): Student =
    Student(member.name, None, member.id)
}

val newMember = Member("abc", "Student", "John")
val student = newMember: Student
```

Or using [implicit class decorator](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/implicit-extension-methods-functions-scala-2-3-dotty/):

```scala
implicit class MemberDecorator(val member: Member) extends AnyVal {
  def toStudent(): Student = Student(member.name, None, member.id)
}

val newMember = Member("abc", "Student", "John")
val student = newMember.toStudent()
```

Comment: I see but currently my whole production code is on Scala 2.13 

Comment: Hmm I tried what you shared but its not working, the implicit that you have declared is it supposed to be placed in helper object or where?
If I put it in helper object it fails and says cannot find the method

I think you can create those implicits only within a class

Comment: @ShivamSahil GuruStron's code compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/VD5LfcQUTo6wb06oErvukQ/1 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/VD5LfcQUTo6wb06oErvukQ/2

Comment: @ShivamSahil [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Comment: @DmytroMitin, I see thank you very much for the entire code in playground. I see you do the conversion as: `val student = newMember: Student` however I was trying out:  `newMember.toStudent`
But thanks anyways, this is what I needed.

Comment: @ShivamSahil Can't you see `newMember.toStudent` at the 2nd link https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/VD5LfcQUTo6wb06oErvukQ/2 ?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Oh sorry I missed it but now I see... However the implicit declaration is supposed to be in some object right? I had a standalone scala file where I had these case classes and I was trying to put `implicit class` there and that's what was throwing me an error but thank you very much again! Now I understand it completelt

Comment: @ShivamSahil Preferably not some object but companion object https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/VD5LfcQUTo6wb06oErvukQ/3 Please read "Where does Scala look for implicits?"